# Sharepoint 2013 Rich text html editor : cannot use the Cut, Copy, Paste

Tags: rich-text, html-editor

I tested to create Rich text field in list and editing in html text editor that also cannot used Cut, Copy or Paste in clipboard panel. when i click these three buttons but no any response and i tested it is work in other text field such as single text field so i searched and tested trusted my site that still not work.

In additional, i tested in other environment that can be paste the text to html editor

Thank you very much.

Any Idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are also having this issue in IE8 (we need to still support this due to older systems currently used in the business), the site is in trusted sites and we can copy and paste into single line text. When we try to copy and paste into rich text we get a blank white screen. (Apologies, I did try to add this as a comment but don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using IE. Make sure you have added the site to Trusted Sites in IE security settings as IE may prevent programmatic access to clipboard by default on Internet zone.

Comment: tkanks ur comments but i tested to trust Sites, still not work.